# Fragment -> Fragment и обратно

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragment

Нужно получить второй фрагмент из первого и наоборот. В коде ниже получается конфликт.

Первый фрагмент

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

protected Fragment2 fragment2 = new Fragment2();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
}
```

Второй фрагмент

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {

protected Fragment1 fragment1 = new Fragment1();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Когда запускаете фрагмент, добавляйте к нему какой-нибудь тэг.

```
public static final String FRAGMENT_TAG = "Fragment1";

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(new Fragment1(), Fragment1.FRAGMENT_TAG)
            .commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Потом по этому тэгу сможете найти фрагмент:

```
Fragment1 fragment = (Fragment1) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(Fragment1.FRAGMENT_TAG);
```